# "Nothing else on earth is worth being preoccupied with"

Tags: word-usage, worth

I know that ***worth*** can be used with a gerundial clause that has a passive meaning:

> A lot of the small towns in the area are definitely ***worth visiting***. ([ldoceonline](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-worth-doing-something))

But can "worth" be used with a passive gerundial clause that finishes with a preposition in this way?

> Nothing else on earth is ***worth*** *being preoccupied with*.

My intended meaning of this sentence would be that *nothing else is worth for anyone to be preoccupied with it*. The sentence I wrote seems correct to me and I like its conciseness. However, it does need a bit of thinking to understand it well. Is there any ambiguity in it?

Comment: A similare usage with ***worried about*** appears to be fairly common: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22worth%20being%20worried%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2019,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

Comment: To the close-voter. I am not looking for an opinion.  I just want to know if this particular structure that does exist, as the comment and answer confirmed, sounds natural and unambiguous to natives.

Comment: Correct. Compare ..... *Some small towns are worth paying a visit to.* / *It’s worth paying a visit to some small towns.* ..... *A cat is worth being preoccupied with.* / *It’s worth being preoccupied with a cat.* ..... [**polarity** alert] _**No** cat is **worth** being preoccupied with._ / _It’s **not worth** being preoccupied with **any** cat._ [**polarity** alert] _**Nothing** else on earth is **worth** being preoccupied with._ / _It’s **not worth** being preoccupied with **anything** else on earth._

Comment: @TinfoilHat You've convinced me. Yet although correct, my sentence still sounds slightly unnatural for some reason. I have decided to change it to _**it is not worth being preoccupied with anything else on earth**_. I think it is more natural this way.

Answer (score 2):

The construction sounds natural in *That's not worth fighting over/about/for.*

My only observation about fev's example is that *being preoccupied with something* happens quite often and the example seems to be inflating its seriousness. Perhaps for that reason it sounds odd. The final preposition isn't a problem. *Nothing on earth is worth worrying yourself sick over* could rise to the occasion.

CGEL covers  *worth, worthwhile* and *for* under **6. Hollow non-finite clauses.** After an explanation of their general properties (6.1) comes:

> **6.2 Gerund-participles**
>
> These are licensed as complement to the adjectives *worth* and
> *worthwhile* and to the preposition *for* with a purpose sense:
>
> *Your idea is certainly worth giving some further thought to*
>
> *The plan is so unpopular that it wouldn't be worthwhile our pursing*
>
> *This knife isn't very good for cutting meat with*
>
> Recall (from §3.2.3) that the superficially similar construction governed by such
> verbs as *need* is a concealed passive not a hollow active, as evident
> from the possibility of having a *by* phrase: *The proposal needs [ ___
> evaluating by a specialist]*. This missing element here, therefore, is
> subject, not object.<sup>*</sup>

The three examples given above are analyzed by showing the missing object:

> *Your idea is certainly worth [giving some further thought to ___ ]*
>
> *The plan is so unpopular that it wouldn't be worthwhile [our pursuing ___ ]*
>
> *This knife isn't very good for [cutting meat with ___ ]*

---

Author's footnote:

> <sup>*</sup>*Bear* occurs with a very limited range of gerund participles, as in the familiar phrase *It doesn't bear thinking about*; the complement
> here is probably a hollow clause rather than a concealed passive.